# What's a good tutorial on reading SharePoint 2013 lists from Visual Basic?

Tags: list, visual-studio

I'm a noob starting out with SP development.  I'm looking for a tutorial to help me access SharePoint lists from a VB project I'm writing.

Comment: Is this going to be an application page in SharePoint or a desktop app (e.g. a forms application)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scott,

Here's an example on [How to: Create, Update, and Delete List Items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee539976%28v=office.14%29.aspx) from an external application.

You can use these methods also within SharePoint itself if you want to deploy a solution with an application page.

[Walkthrough: Creating a SharePoint Application Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231557.aspx)